# Don't these wheels and hubcaps already exist?

Tags: patentability, prior-art, us20140191565

Don't the turbofan wheels oultined in [US20140191565A1](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20140191565/un) already exist from the 1980's, if not before then?

If I do a simple image Google search for "turbofan wheels" I get examples of wheels and hubcaps that show that these have existed for a long time before this.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that wheels that attempt to pump air either toward or more likely away from the brakes have been around for a while. The fourth generation Corvette from 1985 had such wheels. 
[image]
By GPS 56 from New Zealand - 1985 Corvette, CC BY 2.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=38623202

US20140191565A1 is only an application. It may or may not ever become a patent. Indeed, checking in the US Public Pair, I found that it's current status is "Abandoned -- Failure to Respond to an Office Action" as of 10-14-2014. The application received a non-final rejection on 04-03-2014. Non-final rejections are pretty common so the prior art cited by the examiner must have been strong enough to convince the applicant to abandon the application.

I would like to point out that just because there are examples of similar products doesn't necessarily mean new inventions aren't possible. Many times the patent would be for a refinement on an existing product. The patent therefore would only cover the refinement and not the existing products.